# Deserialization in Flink datastream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Here I wrote a string to Kafka topic and flink consumes this topic.The Deserialization is done by using `SimpleStringSchema`.When I need to consume integer value what deserialization method should be used instead of `SimpleStringschema` ???

```
DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>("test2", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
```

Comment: How do You write the int value to the Kafka ??

Comment: by using kafka  producer                                           
code:                                                                                  
            ProducerRecord<Long, Integer> record = new ProducerRecord<Long, Integer>(KafkaConstants.TOPIC_NAME,
            value); where value is a integer.Here I Wrote only value not key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own SerializationSchema

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/serialization/SerializationSchema.java#L32

Or leave it as a string then map the stream out into your required types

Comment: Code :                                                                                            
             DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>("test2", new DeserializationSchema(), properties));

Comment: @Noobie Are you famailiar with Java? You cannot `new` an interface. You may want to skip learning a framework if you don't at least [know the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)